# Passing an unsigned long long to a char parameter in C

Tags: c

I'm looking at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

bool
writebytes (unsigned long long x, int nbytes)
{
  do
    {
      if (putchar (x) < 0)
        return false;
      x >>= CHAR_BIT;
      nbytes--;
    }
  while (0 < nbytes);

  return true;
}
```

and it works (written by my professor).

I understand it is outputting all `nbytes` of the `unsigned long long x` to the screen, and how it's doing this. My only question is, why is it that in C you can pass an `unsigned long long` to a function that takes a `char` as a parameter `putchar(int char)`, and it still interprets it correctly?

Does C only grab the first `CHAR_BIT` of the passed in parameter? Why is there no casting necessary, like:

`putchar( (char) x )`

Comment: I don't believe this code is guaranteed to work.  It may work on a particular platform, with a particular compiler and libraries, but that's a poor basis for deeming something "correct".

Comment: `putchar()` takes an int, not a char. Same [conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) apply though.

Comment: (which if I'm reading it right, conversion of a larger integer type to a smaller signed type is implementation defined unless the value being converted already fits in the smaller type's range. Internally `putchar()` converts its int argument to an unsigned char, which is well defined, but going from an unsigned long long to int first isn't)

Comment: The implicit conversion of an `unsigned long long` to an`int` can overflow (i.e., if it cannot be represented by the new type). I believe the behavior when this happens is implementation defined, and may result in a signal being raised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `putchar(int char)`

The parameter of `putchar` is an `int`. There is no type `int char`.

In `putchar(x)`, the `unsigned long long` `x` is converted to the parameter type `int`, per C 2018 6.5.2.2 7. If the value of `x` is not representable in the `int` type, the result is an implementation-defined value or signal, per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3. Common modern C implementations wrap the value modulo `INT_MAX`+1, which is equivalent to taking the low *n* bytes if two’s complement is used, where *n* is the number of bytes in an `int`.

C 2018 7.21.7.8, 7.21.7.7, and 7.21.7.3 specify that `putchar` writes the character specified by converting its parameter to `unsigned char`. This conversion will wrap the value modulo `UCHAR_MAX`+1, which is equivalent to taking the low byte.

Thus, in most modern C implementations `putchar(x)` will write the low byte of `x` to standard output.

Then `x >>= CHAR_BIT;` shifts the bytes in *x* down one byte, and the loop iterates to write `nbytes` bytes.

Changing `putchar (x)` to `putchar((unsigned char) x)` would improve portability by removing the implementation-defined conversion to `int`.